# Why is my minikube's NodePort service's external IP <none> and not <nodes>?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I'm working through chapter 5.3 of **Kubernetes In Action** by Marko Luska. I'm creating a nodeport service from the [following file](https://github.com/luksa/kubernetes-in-action/blob/master/Chapter05/kubia-svc-nodeport.yaml):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kubia-nodeport
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    nodePort: 30123
  selector:
    app: kubia
```

It works, and I can hit all the IPs I'm expecting to hit (localhost, cluterIP...) but the external IP is shown as `<none>`:

```sh
$ kubectl get svc 
NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes       ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP        17h
kubia-nodeport   NodePort    10.96.191.43   <none>        80:30123/TCP   12s

$ kubectl get rc --show-labels
NAME    DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE   LABELS
kubia   3         3         3       21h   app=kubia

$ kubectl get po --show-labels
NAME          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   LABELS
kubia-fb7h8   1/1     Running   0          17h   app=kubia
kubia-nnkc4   1/1     Running   0          17h   app=kubia
kubia-s88mt   1/1     Running   0          17h   app=kubia
```

Minikube should be showing `<nodes>` as it does in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44112150/external-ip-for-kubernetes-shows-nodes-in-minikube) and this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767164/expose-port-in-minikube). Why is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because this was the case in 2017 and it's not anymore.
The question you're referencing are from 2016 and 2017.

Since then you'll always see `<none>` unless it's a LoadBalancer. See this [particular comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3966#issuecomment-480097796) on github which is from 2019.

Sorry I can't find the PR nor the issue corresponding to that change.